# Sunspot Solr highlight: Always highlight from the beginning

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I need Highlights to be from the beginning of the sentence.

For example:
Indexed Field:

> *I am drinking beer in Downtown Pub.*

If the search query is **drinking beer**, the returned result is:

> *I am **drinking beer** in Downtown Pub.*

What I want is:

> ***drinking beer*** in Downtown Pub.

I am using following Configuration in schema.xml:

```
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="35" side="front" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I think I need to use some configuration of highlighter. But I cannot figure out what and where to put that configuration. I have gone through official document [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) and [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters) but cannot make it work.

I am using [sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot). Any help is appreciated. You may need to be more explicit as I am relatively new to this.